# Start animator of camera from current position/rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an animator controller attached to a camera. The camera animation rotates in the following:
`RotationInitial(0,0,0) and RotationFinal(20,20,20)`. If the camera is at a different rotation such as `RotationCurrent(5,5,5)` and I would like to play the animation from the current position/rotation of the camera that is `RotationInitial(5,5,5)`, how do I set the animation of the animator?

Comment: It's a lot of time since i've used Unity, but is it possible that the solution is to attach an object (invisible) to the camera object (or making a group with camera and this object), making it moving along with the camera object: then you can apply the animation to this object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the camera to go from any rotation, and always end at the same end rotation, I recommend using [Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html). The example provides exactly what you need.